# How can i make this method parallel?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing

I'm having a total blackout at the moment. At the bottom there is a method called drawlines2, how can i make it execute in parallel with the two different arguments? I've tried with implements runnable, but i don't know what to put in the run method, i don't get the grip of it as i want to create threads in the same class.

```
package javastuff;
/**
 * Copyright © 2011 Parag Patil
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * You may not use this file except in compliance with  Apache License, Version 2.0
 * You may obtain a copy of the license at
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

**/

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TreeAnimation {
   public static final int SIZE_X = 1366;
   public static final int SIZE_Y = 768;
   public static void main(final String[] args) {

        final PFrame pframe = new PFrame();         
        pframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);                      
        final PCanvas canvas = new PCanvas((int)pframe.getBounds().getWidth(),(int)pframe.getBounds().getHeight());
        pframe.add(canvas);
        pframe.setVisible(true);
        canvas.setIgnoreRepaint(true);
    }
}
class PFrame extends JFrame {   
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    PFrame() {
        setUndecorated(true);
        final Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        setBounds(0,0,screenSize.width, screenSize.height);
        final KeyStroke escapeKeyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE,0, false);
        Action escapeAction = new AbstractAction() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
            }
        };
        getRootPane().getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(escapeKeyStroke,"ESCAPE");
        getRootPane().getActionMap().put("ESCAPE", escapeAction);
    }
}
class PCanvas extends Canvas{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static int xsize;
    public static int ysize;
    public static final double TRIM_FACTOR = 0.8;
    public static final double INITIAL_LENGTH = 180;
    public static final double EXIT_LENGTH = 2;
    public static final double BRANCH_ANGLE = Math.PI / 9.0;
    public static final int WAIT = 10;

    PCanvas(int size_x, int size_y) {
        super();
        xsize = size_x;
        ysize = size_y - size_y / 20;
        setBackground(Color.black);
        setForeground(Color.white);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(final Graphics g) {
        drawLine2(g, xsize / 2, 0, INITIAL_LENGTH, Math.PI / 2);
    }

    public void drawLine2(final Graphics g, final double x1, final double y1, final double l, final double theta) {

        if (l < EXIT_LENGTH) {
            return;
        }
        final double x2 = x1 + l * Math.cos(theta);
        final double y2 = y1 + l * Math.sin(theta);

        g.drawLine((int)x1, (int)(ysize - y1), (int)x2, (int)(ysize - y2));

            //Here be parallelizable code
        drawLine2(g, x2, y2, l * TRIM_FACTOR, theta - BRANCH_ANGLE);
        drawLine2(g, x2, y2, l * TRIM_FACTOR, theta + BRANCH_ANGLE);
    }
}
```

Comment: You do not want to do that, actually. Please read up on the [Swing Event Dispatching](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html). You should be using SwingUtilities.invokeLater for all drawing tasks.

Comment: @Perception he is already on event dispatch thread. So I think there is no sense to use `invokeLater` for drawing subtasks. I'd say it's impossible to parallelize drawing in java swing.

Comment: @NikitaBeloglazov - that just might be the correct answer - that it makes no sense to try and parallelize drawing tasks - given that all such tasks need to occur on the EDT anyway. My comment doesn't explicitly state that but I would hope that the conclusion is obvious.

Comment: Ok, thanks, but are there any other way of improving the performance of drawing?

Comment: You need to determine if there really is a performance issue.  Use System.nanoTime() to see how long each method call takes. I suspect it will be less than a milli-second, i.e. to fast for a human to see.

Comment: On my machine it took 36 milli-second to compute the lines.  This is the only bit you can parallise and making it 4x faster would make enough difference to see.  It took 320 milli-second to generate the g.drawLine() calls. This is single threaded as you are adding tasks to a queue.  The time it takes to display this is outside your control.  If you want it to appear faster you can generate the tree in an image which you display when complete. (It takes the same time to generate but it looks faster)

Comment: You could try the JavaCL or JavaCV libraries for faster graphics generation.

Answer (score 2):

Note it is not a good idea to draw like that in Swing as pointed out in the comments. But focussing on your OP question specifically, to run the **drawLine2** statements in parallel this is what (in general) you would do:

```
// start first
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        drawLine2(g, x2, y2, l * TRIM_FACTOR, theta - BRANCH_ANGLE);
    }
}).start();
// start second
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        drawLine2(g, x2, y2, l * TRIM_FACTOR, theta + BRANCH_ANGLE);
    }
}).start()
```

Comment: I know but he asked how to run in parallel :)